# How to apply style to a div which is inside an iframe of the page?

Tags: css, iframe

I have been working with css and html for about 6 months. I am confused: why can't I apply styles to a `div` which is inside an `iframe` of my current page?

Answer (score 1):

The inner page is independent when it comes to css styles. You can add styles to the iframe element itself, but if you want to style divs inside it, you would have to reference the css on the child page.

Comment: Why the downvote? It answers the question...