# How to apply css to IFrame with CORS enabled

Tags: css, cors

A subdomain http://board.woodstockschool.in will display a content within Iframe from my.woodstock.ac.in.

In the HTTP headers from my.woodstock.acin it does have this entry:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin => http://board.woodstockschool.in
```

But I'm unable to change the content look using CSS from the board.woodstockschool.in website.

I've tried these as well:

```
a ,iframe a{
color: red !important;
}
```

This changes color of all links except for in the Iframe.

There is an array of questions like [How to apply style to a div which is inside an iframe of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020753/how-to-apply-style-to-a-div-which-is-inside-an-iframe-of-the-page?noredirect=1&lq=1) in here but none with CORS enabled.

I've checked https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#For_Apache but find no mention of css there.

What is the way to apply the css rule from the wrapper site without using any javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style inside an iframe from an external domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873407/how-to-style-inside-an-iframe-from-an-external-domain)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the way to apply the css rule from the wrapper site

There is no way.

The closest you could come would be to:

- Set a query string on the iframe's `src` and then have the embedded page use server side code to stick a `<link>` to the stylesheet in based on that.
- Use `postMessage` to send a message (possibly including the URL of the stylesheet) to the embedded page and then have JavaScript running on the embedded page add the `<link>`.

CORS will not help or hinder you in this. It's entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @Kaiido — No, it doesn't. "CORS will not help or hinder you in this. It's entirely irrelevant."

Answer (score 0):

The best way may be the following (in case you control both sites):

1) set the iframe link with `style` parameter, like:

```
http://your_site.com/target.php?style=a%7Bcolor%3Ared%7D
```

(the last phrase is `a{color:red}`  encoded by `urlencode` function)

2) set the receiver page `target.php` like this:

```
<head>
..........
<style><?php echo filter_var($_GET['style'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);?> </style>
..........
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: `urldecode` attempts to double decode the data. PHP will decode it automatically before populating `$_GET`.

Comment: yes, thanks @Quentin , i have modified the answer to reflect your advise.